# Put and Get Selected Radio Button from Radio Group using SharedPreferences

Tags: android-fragments

want to store selected radio from and radio group and once that fragment is again launch , previous selected radio should be selected , I tried but not able to get it .

I need to store selected position on Click of button only .

This is code which I am using :

```
radiogender=(RadioGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);



        radiogender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                // find which radio button is selected
                if(checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You: Dude !!!", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if(checkedId == R.id.radioButton2) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You: Babe !!!", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } 
            }

        });
```

Comment: You have to store something in preferences and then use it to set checked. Your code doesn't do anything like that. Have you tried using preferences?

Comment: I had tried many way , but cant figure it out , a sample code will be much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    radiogender=(RadioGroup)rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    radioButton1=(RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    radioButton2=(RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);

    SharedPreferences myPrefs=context.getSharedPreferences("general",context.MODE_PRIVATE);  //you can give any name in place of general to your preferences

            radiogender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                    // find which radio button is selected
                    if(checkedId == R.id.radioButton1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You: Dude !!!", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //save in preferences
                        myPrefs.edit().putInt("selected",1).commint(); 

                    } else if(checkedId == R.id.radioButton2) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You: Babe !!!", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //save in preferences 

                       myPrefs.edit().putInt("selected",2).commit();
                    } 
                }

            });

//check if there is any value in preferences and set accordingly 

int s=myPrefs.getInt("selected",0);   //will return 0 when nothing is stored 
if(s==1){
  radioButton1.setChecked(true);
} else if(s==2){
  radioButton2.setChecked(true);
}
```

To add a value in preferences, you first use the `edit()` tag and then use `putInt` or `putString` ,etc. to add value to the preferences.

Example `putInt("selected",1 );`  Here the 'selected' is the key or name that you provide so that you can fetch the value with that key. And '1' is the value to be stored against that key.

Then use `commit()` to save the value in preferences.

When you need to fetch a value, you use `getInt` or `getString` etc. to fetch the value.

Example `getInt("selected",0);`.  Here `selected` is the key whose value you want to fetch. `0` is the default value that will be supplied in case there is no value under the key that you have provided.

Hope this helps :)